# Optimizing loading times on highstock sql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, highcharts

I'm using highstock to virtualize some weather data stored in a continuously expanding MySQL database. As the database is getting bigger, the website loading times increased quite a bit. At first I was glad that I've got highstock working as I'm not really into JavaScript and PHP but now I'm looking for a way to improve the loading times.

Right now I'm using 4 different series to show temperatur, humidity, luminance and soil humidity. To import the data I'm using one php script for each series as the last code shows. I don't know how to use only one php script to pass all data over at once neither if that would save any time. But it is definetly the php scripts that take the longest as running them independently takes some time.

[Preview Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88dbT.jpg)

My index.html: https://pastebin.com/KUZfbLjC (there are some strange spaces/tabs that are not in the original file for some reason)

sql_temperature.php:

```
if (date("I")) {$offset = 7200;} #Offset for daylight saving time
else {$offset = 3600;}

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', '***', '***');

$sql = "select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Timestamp), Temperature from sensors";
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
   $datetime = ($row[0] + $offset) * 1000;
   $data[] = array((float)$datetime,(float) $row[1]);
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

So if there is anything to optimize here please let me know.

Comment: It will be quite slow if you send all the data to the client side every time.  Try looking into a way to only send the correct date range to the client.  (Then if they change the data range, the data will have to be reloaded, but it should be much faster.)  Or if you don't need old data, you could only send a certain date range of data (ie the last x months) by adding a where clause to your query.

Comment: I found this example about async loading of 17million points and it is loading incredibly fast. http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/lazy-loading/ Is this now due to the async loading or because they are using very powerful hardware?

Comment: In this php you can see that they're kinda "cheating" as they're using different tables for minutes, hours, day and months. That way a maximum of 3000 points are loaded at the same time. That's why it's so fast

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add the link: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/from-sql.php

Comment: If you're loading more than 3,000 points that sounds like a good start.  The are also filtering by the start and end times.  If you run into problems implementing that feel free to start another question with the code and the problem you are having.  We don't usually implement things for people on StackOverflow, just help them fix a bug in there implementation or find the right function to use, which I think you have now.

Comment: To load that few points I'd have to change my whole database structure. Is there a way to optimize my php script? Maybe load all data with only one script?

Comment: You can time the different parts using the console and network tab in your browser but it's probably show because the browser has to parse all those points in addition to the server having to print them. It's only going to get worse long term to. You can at least filter by the start and end date range. Using date operations on the database you should be able to make the other filters also without having to have new tables.